# Django Bulk Upload to DB with CSV Upload - All are uploaded and only one not

Tags: python, django, csv, file-upload

I am trying to upload some big files to my Django DB. When i do that, all of the files are uploaded, and only one is not uploading. There is no error, but the upload is not been made. The one that is not uploading is the last ***Ofac_Sdn_Comments*** function. Please note that there is no error and also the DB is not updated accordingly.

If someone could help me, I would owe you a lot.

Please find below my models:

```
class Ofac_Sdn(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    b_i = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    programe= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    more_info = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_call_sign = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_type= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_dwt = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    tonnage = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    vessel_flag = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_owner= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    dob_aka= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ofac_sdn"
    def __str__(self):
        return ((self.number,  self.name,  self.programe))
class Ofac_Add(models.Model):
    number = models.ForeignKey(Ofac_Sdn, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    n= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    adresa = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    oras_zip = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    stat = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    ceva = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ofac_add"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.number_id, self.adresa ,  self.oras_zip, self.stat, self.ceva


class Ofac_Alt(models.Model):
    number = models.ForeignKey(Ofac_Sdn, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ceva = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    aka = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    name_of_aka = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    a = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ofac_alt"
    def __str__(self):
        return ((self.number_id,  self.aka, self.name_of_aka))

class Ofac_Sdn_Comments(models.Model):
    number = models.ForeignKey(Ofac_Sdn, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    more_info = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ofac_sdn_comments"
    def __str__(self):
        return ((self.number_id, self.more_info))
```

This is my bulk upload function:

```
import csv, sys, os

project_dir = "/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/import_save/"
sys.path.append(project_dir)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='ofac.settings'

import django
django.setup()

from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Sdn
from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Add
from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Alt
from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Sdn_Comments

file = '/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/import_save/sdn.csv'
file1 = '/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/import_save/add.csv'
file2='/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/import_save/alt.csv'
file3='/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/import_save/sdn_comments.csv'

data = csv.reader(open(file),delimiter=",")
for row in data:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Sdn()
        post.number = row[0]
        post.name = row[1]
        post.b_i=row[2]
        post.programe=row[3]
        post.more_info=row[4]
        post.vessel_call_sign=row[5]
        post.vessel_type=row[6]
        post.vessel_dwt=int(row[7])
        post.tonnage=int(row[8])
        post.vessel_flag=row[9]
        post.vessel_owner=row[10]
        post.dob_aka=row[11]
        post.save()

data1 = csv.reader(open(file1),delimiter=",")
for row in data1:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Add()
        post.number_id = row[0]  #am pus un _id la foreign key k asa stokeaza django foreign key-ul
        post.n = row[1]
        post.adresa=row[2]
        post.oras=row[3]
        post.stat=row[4]
        post.s=row[5]
        post.save()

data2 = csv.reader(open(file2),delimiter=",")
for row in data2:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Alt()
        post.number_id = row[0]  #am pus un _id la foreign key k asa stokeaza django foreign key-ul
        post.ceva = row[1]
        post.aka=row[2]
        post.name_of_aka=row[3]
        post.a=row[4]
        post.save()

data3 = csv.reader(open(file3),delimiter=",")
for row in data3:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Sdn_Comments()
        post.number_id = row[0]  #am pus un _id la foreign key k asa stokeaza django foreign key-ul
        post.more_info = row[1]
```

Here is some info about the way how the information from the csv looks like--all that info is only in one line in the actual CSV ( *I've put it on many lines here just to be seen properly* )the one with the issue:

```
     12300,"Z S.A.S.; Linked To: RED MUNDIAL INMOBILIARIA, 
S.A. DE C.V.; Linked To: FUNDACION PARA EL BIENESTAR Y EL PORVENIR; 
Linked To: C.I. METALURGIA EXTRACTIVA DE COLOMBIA S.A.S.;
Linked To: GRUPO MUNDO MARINO, S.A.; 
Linked To: C.I. DISERCOM S.A.S.; 
Linked To: C.I. OKCOFFEE COLOMBIA S.A.S.; 
Linked To: C.I. OKCOFFEE INTERNATIONAL S.A
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to do save

```
for row in data3:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Sdn_Comments()
        post.number_id = row[0]
        post.more_info = row[1]
        # NEXT LINE
        post.save()
```

Comment: glad to help you)